# Why won't Facebook "Like" Button Scale on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, css, webkit, facebook-like, css-transforms

Using CSS properties for `transform` I can scale items across all browsers. For example, given the HTML `<div class="scaled">scaled text</div>` and the CSS `.scaled { transform:scale(2.0,2.0); -webkit-transform:scale(2.0,2.0); }` I can enlarge the text in that `div` 2x. This works on Chrome and Safari on desktop and iOS (using `-ms-transform` gets it on IE).

However, for some reason, when I apply this scaling to the Facebook "Like" button, the scaling doesn't work on iOS webkit browsers (e.g. Safari, Chrome). It *does* work on desktop Safari and Chrome, however, and the same properties applied to text works on both desktop and mobile browsers.

What's going on? Why won't the Like button scale on iOS even though everything else does? Example code is below. You can [see it on the web here](http://criticalviewer.com/likebutton/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.scaled { -webkit-transform: scale(2.0, 2.0); transform: scale(2.0, 2.0); }
.box { margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; margin-bottom: 50px; }
#container { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">not scaled</div>
  <div class="scaled box">scaled 2.0</div>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=1604164706533585";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <div class="fb-like scaled" data-href="http://codepen.io/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And now all of the sudden the Like button isn't showing at all on desktop Chrome (in the codepen demo). Working on it.

Comment: updated question and link above to remove codepen demo, now providing example on the web (which works as described across browsers/OS')